# Compiler error at function call in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, declaration, signature

I'm relatively new to C++ and am learning by going through questions. I'm attempting to use getopt to manage my input and I've created functions to help make the program clearer. Here's what I'm doing (snippets):

```
void processArgs(int,char *,char **,long int *);

void processArgs(int argc, char ** argv, long int * res)
{
  globalArgs.startTerm = NULL;
  globalArgs.endTerm = NULL;
  globalArgs.outFileName = NULL;
  globalArgs.verbosity = 0;
  int minimumArgs = 1;

  //Check for minimum number of parameters
  if (argc<minimumArgs){
    displayUsage();
  }
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
  int * results=NULL;
  processArgs(argc,argv,results);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the following compile, I get:

```
g++ -std=c++0x fibonacci.cpp -o fibonacci
fibonacci.cpp: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
fibonacci.cpp:68: error: no matching function for call to âprocessArgs(int&, char**&, int*&)â
fibonacci.h:3: note: candidates are: void processArgs(int, char*, char**, long int*)
fibonacci.cpp:46: note:                 void processArgs(int, char**, long int*)
```

Can someone please help me to understand the problem? I'm sure its related to my reduced understanding to how the pointers related to argv are working.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Your description isn't very good: it's not the function call that failed, but you got a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function signatures are not matching

`void processArgs(int,char *,char **,long int *);`

`void processArgs(int argc, char ** argv, long int * res)`

check for `char *`

you can remove `char *` from `void processArgs(int,char *,char **,long int *);` or you can remove the complete line.

here because you are already defining function above `main()` so no need to use `void processArgs(int,char *,char **,long int *);` before function, as compiler is already getting the function signature before compiling `main()`.

Comment: I'd add a suggestion about reformatting and/or omitting the declaration in this case.

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't see that, thank. you. I was always told to add a declaration in a header file and then define the function in the main file. Is this not the case then?

Comment: The main concept is you need to provide the function signature before a function call, if you are putting the signature in a header file then the function signature can be provided to multiple files where that function call is required only by including that header file.

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that these two function declarations declare different functions because they have different number of parameters

```
void processArgs(int,char *,char **,long int *);

void processArgs(int argc, char ** argv, long int * res);
```

However it is not the reason of the error.

The error message of your compiler is confusing. The problem is that in the second function declaration (that in the same time is a definition) the third parameter is declared as having type

```
long int *
```

However you call the function passing to it as an argument an object (variable results) of type

```
int *
```

Here is your definition of the passed to function object and the function call

```
  int * results=NULL;
  processArgs(argc,argv,results);
```

There is no implicit conversion from `int *` to `long int *`

So the compiler issues the error.

Comment: +1 Your answer may be even better, if you reorder the arguments. Looking closely on the compiler error, is a good idea - most readers obviously stopped at the first obvious error. BTW: there is a `problen` in your answer.

Comment: @Wolf What is there the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48679/discussion-between-wolf-and-vlad-from-moscow)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as **rajenpandit** already said, your declaration and definition signatures are different.
Secondly, I suppose that it fails to call the function due to the last argument: the function expects `long int *`, while you provide it with a `int *`.

Comment: Compiler see second things first. :)

Answer (score 1):

The *first obvious problem* (for programmers!) in your code - [rajenpandit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092571/2932052) already stated it - is a [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) mismatch - but - as [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092862/2932052) found - the *compiler* did not stop there. The **call itself did not match any of the two declarations** you gave. This is what the compiler says.

---

BTW:
The easiest way to declare a function in C/C++: **use the clipboard** (add the semicolon manually):

```
void processArgs(int argc, char ** argv, long int * res);

void processArgs(int argc, char ** argv, long int * res)
{
    // your function body
}
```

The copy&paste method has also another advantage: the function declaration then contains also **parameter names**, which is especially helpful if there is more than one parameter. Many IDEs also display these names as a hint when you type the call.